# Is it possible to create from scratch a vagrant box with a custom password?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

There are many tutorials that say that it is possible to create a vagrant box from scratch by using a Ubuntu iso and Virtualbox, however, always they use as a username vagrant and password vagrant by default. Is it possible to use another password? When the basic credential vagrant-vagrant is used, this is hidden (or it's not necessary to write it) in Vagrantfile. Would it happen the same with another password by default?

Answer (score 1):

You decide which username/password that you will use.

For example there are packer templates available in github, most of them will create the vagrant user (such as https://github.com/boxcutter/ubuntu/blob/master/script/vagrant.sh) - you can easily change it to your own username.

As for password, you can set it from the script as well, but its more convenient to use the ssh key to login. If you wish to login with a password, you'll set the password from Vagrantfile (`config.ssh.password`)

Comment: Hi Frederic, My question is because I want to create a private vagrant box where only I know the credentials. This is because I need to share a Vagrant box with a client and I don't want he can enter it. The client only would need to start a virtual machine and open his browser because of this is a Web service. but if he wants to connect via SSH to see the source code, for example, it's not possible at less he guesses the password although I know this is not a perfect solution. BTW when you use config.ssh.password this pass is in plain text and I don't need this. Regards

Comment: vagrant is a dev tool, if it cannot ssh into the VM, it cannot do its magic (setting ip, hostname, sync folder and so on) - if you dont want anyone to ssh into the VM, why dont you deliver the virtualbox VM ? you install everything and setup services correctly, do not provide them with the password and they will only start the VM from virtualbox and access the running servers within the VM but they will not be able to ssh into it

Comment: Yes, in fact, I'm doing this, right now. I thought that by using Vagrant was possible but it seems to be that the best option is to use Virtualbox directly and disable things like grub to avoid password recovery, etc.  Thanks